# Getting a Module Not Found error in PyCharm IDE while using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python 3.9 in windows OS.
I recently installed matplotlib using the following command in command prompt:

```
cd C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
python -m pip install matplotlib
```

(was following the instructions from the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9RdLbrTI_3A&t=97s)

I was trying to run a simple code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,1])
plt.show()
```

This code was working perfectly fine in Idle. But when I switched to PyCharm IDE, there is this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\DataVisualization\Test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

What went wrong here?

Comment: create a new project and disable virtual environment

Comment: @AbhimanyuSharma, Sorry, I'm new to this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env